# How to set Minimum Radius for Circle Pack in D3JS?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

Can anyone guide me how I can modify https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063269, in a way that the circles have a minimum radius?

If the circles have a really small radius their inner text is hidden, which I would like to avoid.

Comment: this should be helpful https://www.dashingd3js.com/svg-text-element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the minimum size of the circles using different approaches. This answer deals with [pack.radius](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/blob/master/README.md#pack_radius):

> If radius is specified, sets the pack layout’s radius accessor to the specified function and returns this pack layout.

First, we set a scale. You can see that the minimum value here is 20 (and the maximum is 50):

```
var sizeScale = d3.scaleSqrt()
   .range([20,50]);
```

Then, we use that scale in `pack.radius`:

```
pack.radius(d=>sizeScale(d.value));
```

Here is a demo using the same code you linked, from Mike Bostock: https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/9590a06db119c7a67acdfd3c5b5f1e0a

Comment: I was not feeling very comfortable writing this answer because this question deals with something that I really care: telling the truth with data... or, even better, not **to lie with data**. Changing the size of the circles just to show the text is a kind of lie, because the size of the circles encodes information.